# Calculating the distance between a point within 2 cuboids

Tags: geometry

I am trying to write a function that returns a value between 0 and 1 that represents how close a point within a cuboid is to the surface of another, smaller, cuboid. However, I am getting an issue in the corners of the cuboid.

Currently, when the point (blue circles on the diagram below) is between the two cuboids (or rectangles in the image), the value returned is the length between the point and the inner cuboid (orange line) divided by the length between the two faces.

[image]

However, if the value is in a corner, this approach does not work. In the game I am making, this function is used to control the opacity of a material, but it produces strange visuals.

[image]

In the case of the image above, the expected behaviour is the closer the point on the object is to the cuboid, the more opaque it is.

The code I am using to check if a point is between two cuboids is below, the information I have available is the centre point of the cuboid, the size of the inner cuboid, the extra size of the outer cuboid and the position of the point.

```
bool InsideCube(float3 centre, float3 offset, float3 pointPosition) {
    float minX = centre[0] - offset[0];
    float maxX = centre[0] + offset[0];
    float minY = centre[1] - offset[1];
    float maxY = centre[1] + offset[1];
    float minZ = centre[2] - offset[2];
    float maxZ = centre[2] + offset[2];

    return pointPosition[0] >= minX &&
        pointPosition[0] <= maxX &&
        pointPosition[1] >= minY &&
        pointPosition[1] <= maxY &&
        pointPosition[2] >= minZ &&
        pointPosition[2] <= maxZ;
}

void FlatDistance_float(float3 centre, float3 size, float3 extend, float3 vertexPos, out float distance)
{
    float3 offset = size / 2;

    if (InsideCube(centre, offset, vertexPos))
    {
        distance = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        float3 extendOffset = extend / 2;
        float3 extendedPoints = offset + extendOffset;

        if (InsideCube(centre, extendedPoints, vertexPos))
        {
            float xOffset = centre[0] + offset[0];
            float distanceToX = abs(vertexPos[0] - xOffset);
            float fadeX = saturate(distanceToX / extendOffset[0]);

            float xOffsetNeg = centre[0] - offset[0];
            float distanceToXNeg = abs(vertexPos[0] - xOffsetNeg);
            float fadeXNeg = saturate(distanceToXNeg / extendOffset[0]);

            float yOffset = centre[1] + offset[1];
            float distanceToY = abs(vertexPos[1] - yOffset);
            float fadeY = saturate(distanceToY / extendOffset[1]);

            float yOffsetNeg = centre[1] - offset[1];
            float distanceToYNeg = abs(vertexPos[1] - yOffsetNeg);
            float fadeYNeg = saturate(distanceToYNeg / extendOffset[1]);

            float zOffset = centre[2] + offset[2];
            float distanceToZ = abs(vertexPos[2] - zOffset);
            float fadeZ = saturate(distanceToZ / extendOffset[2]);

            float zOffsetNeg = centre[2] - offset[2];
            float distanceToZNeg = abs(vertexPos[2] - zOffsetNeg);
            float fadeZNeg = saturate(distanceToZNeg / extendOffset[2]);

            float minX = min(fadeX, fadeXNeg);
            float minY = min(fadeY, fadeYNeg);
            float minZ = min(fadeZ, fadeZNeg);
            float minXY = min(minX, minY);
            distance = min(minXY, minZ);
        }
        else
        {
            distance = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use the distance from the outer square and have two regions - activated based on location.

Comment: @Moti Thanks for the comment but I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: You have two types of regions - you need to identify in which you are and than make calculation to fit the corner. Calculating the corner with side condition could lead to strange results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the advice from [Moti](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/213654/moti), I was able to solve this by using a second point to work out which side of the cuboid the point was on. Fortunately Unity provides this information and I could just access the vertex's normal.

If anyone is interested the code I used was

```
//UNITY_SHADER_NO_UPGRADE
#ifndef FADE_ALPHA_INCLUDED
#define FADE_ALPHA_INCLUDED

bool InsideCube(
    float3 centre,
    float3 offset,
    float3 pointPosition)
{
    float minX = centre.x - offset.x;
    float maxX = centre.x + offset.x;
    float minY = centre.y - offset.y;
    float maxY = centre.y + offset.y;
    float minZ = centre.z - offset.z;
    float maxZ = centre.z + offset.z;

    return pointPosition.x >= minX &&
        pointPosition.x <= maxX &&
        pointPosition.y >= minY &&
        pointPosition.y <= maxY &&
        pointPosition.z >= minZ &&
        pointPosition.z <= maxZ;
}

float CalculateAlpha(
    float vertexPosition,
    float userPosition,
    float offsetSize,
    float extendedOffset)
{
    float distance;
    if (vertexPosition > userPosition)
    {
        float offset = userPosition + offsetSize;
        distance = vertexPosition - offset;
    }
    else
    {
        float offset = userPosition - offsetSize;
        distance = offset - vertexPosition;
    }
    return 1 - saturate(distance / extendedOffset);
}

void FadeAlpha_float(
    float3 normalPosition,
    float3 vertexPosition,
    float3 userPosition,
    float3 opaqueCube,
    float3 fadeInCube,
    out float alpha)
{
    float3 offsetSize = opaqueCube / 2;
    if (InsideCube(userPosition, offsetSize, vertexPosition))
    {
        alpha = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        float3 extendedOffsetSize = fadeInCube / 2;
        if (InsideCube(userPosition, offsetSize + extendedOffsetSize, vertexPosition))
        {
            float3 absNormals = abs(normalPosition);

            if (absNormals.x > 0)
            {
                alpha = CalculateAlpha(
                    vertexPosition.x,
                    userPosition.x,
                    offsetSize.x,
                    extendedOffsetSize.x);
            }
            else if (absNormals.y > 0)
            {
                alpha = CalculateAlpha(
                    vertexPosition.y,
                    userPosition.y,
                    offsetSize.y,
                    extendedOffsetSize.y);
            }
            else if (absNormals.z > 0)
            {
                alpha = CalculateAlpha(
                    vertexPosition.z,
                    userPosition.z,
                    offsetSize.z,
                    extendedOffsetSize.z);
            }
            else
            {
                alpha = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alpha = 0;
        }
    }
}

#endif // FADE_ALPHA_INCLUDED
```